# Elif statement only returning correct output every other time

Tags: python

I'm completely new to Python (and programming in general) and I can't wrap my head around why this piece of code doesn't work

```py
posx = 0
posy = 0
doForever = True

while doForever == True:
  if input() == "forward":
    posy += 1
    print(posy)
  elif input() == "backward":
    posy -= 1
    print(posy)
```

It's supposed to check if the player inputs "forward" or "backward" and update the ypos accordingly. But what actually happens is that if you input "backward", it only works exactly half of the time. The "forward" one works correctly, but the "backward" only returns the updated variable every other time it's used. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only have one input, so simply create one variable and do all conditions on that:

```
posx = 0
posy = 0
doForever = True

while doForever == True:
  s = input()
  if s == "forward":
    posy += 1
    print(posy)
  elif s == "backward":
    posy -= 1
    print(posy)
```

Answer (score 0):

As @U9-Forward has said and you can simply your while instruction without `== True`

```
posx = 0
posy = 0
doForever = True

while doForever:
  s = input()
  if s == "forward":
    posy += 1
    print(posy)
  elif s == "backward":
    posy -= 1
    print(posy)
```

Comment: Just get rid of  `doForever` and use `while True:`.